# TextView Alignment Issue on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having two `TextView` in `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_discounted_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_between_prices"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="AED200000000.00"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_sub_normal"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_unit_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="AED200000000000.00"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_emphasized"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I want something like if 2nd TextView doesnt come in single line than it should shift to second line.

Issue is :

[image]

With `SingeLine=true`

[image]

With `maxLine=1`

[image]

What I want :

[image]

Comment: try using the `maxlines` property for the textview

Comment: Still it wont go to next line

Comment: If your first TextView value is "ABCD" then Second TextView should start next to first TextView right???

Comment: Yes it should start from next

Comment: I have an idea to add those two values in a single textview. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: But with that will this be solved ? Like it will give be in 2 different lines if the data is big enough to get into single line

Comment: Where you can check one condition that text size greater than certain values.

Comment: How can you depend on that because this will than depend on the screen size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161959/discussion-between-gowtham-subramaniam-and-abdevelopers).

Comment: you can use **FlexboxLayout**

Comment: Sow your nedd is "How to check if a TextView String has been trimmed (marquee)?"

Comment: No? My issue like if the textview doesnt fit in that line than it should go to next line not line creating 3 lines like in my question

Comment: @ABDevelopers check my below ans

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

and also add maxline and singleline to textView

Answer (score -1):

It is easy put your text views in a `RelativeLayout` and all you need to set `layout_above` or `layout_bottom` for your TextViews
or you can change `orientation:vertical` and then the gravity works.
You can also set `layout_gravity`

Comment: Dynamically I can do with LinearLayout too. But the thing is it must be something just with Xml

Comment: Provide Some suggestions dynamically with same code

Comment: do what i said. change orientation to vertical